# When creating a sharepoint site can list content be mixed with web-parts?

Tags: 2010, web-part, web-services

When creating a sharepoint site can list content be mixed with web-parts ?

So the list content can easily be exposed with a web-service and the web parts can exist alongside the list content parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access SharePoint list content through web services and there are also web parts to show the content of lists and libraries so this content can be mingled on a page with other web parts as required.

Comment: thanks!, to display the content of a list within a web-part : something like this : ? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-content-query-web-part-HA010174134.aspx

Comment: The CQWP that you have linked will allow you to get content from one list/library or multiple depending on how you configure it.  Igaud has added a good link below to give you more idea about the list view web part.  You can easily add these through the browser if the list or library is on the site you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list view web part that can be added to any web part page - SharePoint creates one for each list. There are more details here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-sharepoint-services-help/list-view-web-part-HA010024052.aspx

Some of the built in site templates use this, e.g. when they display a view of Shared Documents on the home page.